# Is it possible to call a modal popup (javascript) in MVC controller return

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, popup, bootstrap-modal

I am wondering if it is possible to call a JavaScript method (which displays a Modal as a popup) in the return method of a controller.

```
string name = home.entityDetails.Name;
if (name == " " || name == null)
{
    return PartialView("NotFound");
}
```

Where `return PartialView("Not found");` is called, is it possible to return a JavaScript method that shows a modal?

Comment: Not really, but how are you posting to the controller? If you use AJAX to POST to the controller you can show the modal on a successful response? Or are you perhaps talking about showing it on page load?

Comment: No. The best you can do is return a view that calls a JS method using something like the `window.onload` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to handle this is using Bootstrap modals and javascript inside your view.

Since you're using Partial view, I assume that you have another parent view such as Index View. You can attach html for your modals using javascript inside parent view, and then open your Partial view from Parent view. Here is an example of the same.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div class="container">
        <a href="@Url.Action("NotFound", "Name")" id="NotFound" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="NotFound-Model" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-    labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-    label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Holiday</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="divForNotFound">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT to handle Bootstrap Modal

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#NotFound').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.get(this.href, function (response) {
                   $('.divForNotFound').html(response);
               });
                $('#Add-NotFound').modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                }, 'show');
            });
    }
```

Assuming you have a partial view NotFound.cshtml

```
@model Name.NotFoundModel
using (Ajax.BeginForm("NotFound", "Name", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "div-record", OnSuccess = "$('.close').click()" }))
{
    <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table-bordered table-responsive table table-striped">
            <tr class="col-lg-12">
                <th class="label-primary">
                    @Html.Label("NotFoundLabel")
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Hope that helps!