# Unable to display Modal popup in the same page MVC

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, razor, model-view-controller

I have a requirement where I need to display a Modal popup. When the user clicks on the link inside a grid, then that has to open a modal popup with the respective values. But currently it is taking me to a new page instead of displaying it as a modal popup in the same page. Can someone have a look at this an tell me what is going wrong?

Popup is being called here:

```
grid.AddColumn("ProductName", "Product",
             format: (item) =>
             {
                 return Warehouse.Helpers.HtmlHelpers.DialogFormLink2(Html, item.ProductName, @Url.Content("~/Service/ProductCategory/ProductTransactionsPopupView?ProductID=" + @item.ProductID + "&ProgramID=" + Model.ProgramID + "&Status=" + item.ProductStatus + "&ProductRequestID=" + ViewBag.ProductRequestID), null, "Product History", "dialog", "", @Url.Action("ProductProfile"));
             });
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult ProductTransactionsPopupView(int ProductID, string ProductStatus, int? ProductRequestID = null)
        {
            var Program = GetProgram();

            var mdl = new ProductTransactionsViewModel { ProgramID = Program.ProgramID, ProductID = ProductID };

            try
            {
                var ProductTransactionResponse = _ServiceProduct.GetProductTransactions(Program.ProgramID, User.Name, ProductID);

                mdl.ProductID = ProductTransactionResponse.ProductId;
                mdl.Transactions = ProductTransactionResponse.ProductTransactions.ToList();
                mdl.ProductName = ProductTransactionResponse.Product != null ? ProductTransactionResponse.Product.ProductName : "";                
                mdl.ProductStatus = ProductStatus;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                mdl.ErrorMessage = "An error occured.";
            }

            ViewBag.ProductRequestID = ProductRequestID;

            return View("ProductTransactions", mdl);
        }
```

Model View:

```
@model Warehouse.Product.ProductTransactionsViewModel
@using Warehouse.Helpers;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Product Transactions";
    ViewBag.ProgramID = Model.ProgramID;
    ViewBag.ProductName = Model.ProductName;
    ViewBag.ProductID = Model.ProductID;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PRPopupsLayout.cshtml";

    var PRID = (int?)ViewBag.ProductRequestID;
}

<div class="DisplayMessage">
</div>

 <div class="popupContentContainer">
    @Html.Partial("_ProductTransactions")
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
    @if(Model.ProductStatus == "Active")
    {
    <input type="button" value="Generate Product Document" id="ProductInquiry" name="ProductInquiry" class="grey button" />
    }
    <input type="button" value="Exit" id="exit" name="exit" class="grey button" />
</div>
```

Comment: What is `Warehouse.Helpers.HtmlHelpers.DialogFormLink2`? Is that 3rd party code? Then you should mention what library it came from. Is it your own code? then you need to include the implementation here. What we really need is a [MCVE].

Comment: Yes it is our own code. It is just a model where there are properties.

Comment: That doesn't look like a model. That looks like it generates HTML. Again, you need to provide us with a [MCVE].

Comment: Here is a link to my post on a question regarding Bootstrap modal popup - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501048/is-it-possible-to-call-a-modal-popup-javascript-in-mvc-controller-return/52501685#52501685 Please mark it as an answer if it resolves your problem. Thanks!